# When Benchmarking my code, this one regex multiples the runtime of a loop by 4

Tags: c#, regex

The offending regex is

```
TldCheck = new Regex(@"(live|lycos|mail|yahoo|gmail|msn|netzero|peoplepc|sbcglobal|verizon|hotmail|earthlink|cox|bellsouth|comcast|barracuda|att|aol)\.?(com|net|org)@", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

When it's run against the list, it causes some major lag. Is there anyway to rewrite this? The purpose it clear email lists of emails like:

```
adsfyahoocom@aol.com
adsfyahoocom@comcast.net
adfadyahoocom@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 6):

One way to speed this up is to do the following. First store all of the domains in a `HashSet<string>`.  This is a very efficient lookup structure and allows for quick tests of matches

```
HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
hashSet.Add("live");
hashSet.Add("lycos");
...
```

Next you'll need to split every email address such that you can get the domain out.  Easiest way is to do the following

```
string GetDomain(string email) {
  var index = email.IndexOf('@');
  var end = email.IndexOf('.', index + 1);
  return email.Substring(index, end - index);
}
```

Then you can just test as so

```
if (hashSet.Contains(GetDomain("foo@bar.com")) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Removal of regex and unnecessary object instances. I would +2 if I could :)

Comment: @OP: If your domains might be mixed case, you'll either need a `ToLower` in `GetDomain` or to use `HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: Though your answer is nice, I'm looking for domains before the @. What I did was just convert the regex above to a bunch of indexofs that had to be before the @. Thanks though for the info. This was for list cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

A couple questions for you:
- Are you actually looking to match e-mail addresses from these domain names? Or is this just to catch the most common e-mail addresses?
- Do you know any characteristics of the data you're searching? For example, any chance it's a large dataset that's sparsely populated with matches?

I don't usually code in C# so I don't know the exact syntax, but you could replace the whole list of domain names with just @[^.]+.?(com|net|org). I'd expect it to be faster if it only has to make one check instead of comparing against each of those domain names (and the various case combinations). Then, if you really only want that subset of domain names, you can make a second pass through this smaller dataset to narrow it down to what you want.

Comment: The code was to catch tld domains that were in email addresses before the @. I changed my code to use a series of indexofs and shreded 17 seconds off per 4 million records.